# ul li show/hide with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm Trying to create A drop down menu.

but i couldn't get the sub menu item to hide on mouseout.

It hides itself on every move

My jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('ul ul').hide();
        $('ul li.top_menu_first a').removeAttr("href");
        $('ul li.top_menu_first > a').mouseover(function(event) {
            $(this).parent().find('ul').show('slow');
        });

        $('ul li.top_menu_first ul').mouseout(function(event) {
            $('ul ul').hide('slow');
        });
    });
</script>
```

My HTMLcode:

```
<div id="top_menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="top_menu_first"><a href="http://google.com">ABC</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>1</a></li>
                <li><a>2</a></li>
                <li><a>3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>   
        <li class="top_menu_first"><a>DEF</a></li>
        <li class="top_menu_first"><a>GHI</a></li>
        <li class="top_menu_first"><a>JKL</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>4</a></li>
                <li><a>5</a></li>
                <li><a>6</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>   
        <li class="top_menu_first"><a>MNO</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>7</a></li>
                <li><a>8</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li class="top_menu_first">
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Please if anyone can help

Comment: `</li class="top_menu_first">` ??

Comment: Try it with `mouseleave` instead of `mouseout`.

Comment: I'd try something like this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gmeMb/1/) ??

Comment: @adeneo You should make it an answer it works better

Comment: @adeneo hover your mouse multiple times, it goes crazy, [stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Comment: @stop-elclnrs so does the current implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code keeps track of the sub menu mouseOut . 
I assume you want the sub menu to hide when it's mouse out from menu name.

delete `ul`
from `$('ul li.top_menu_first ul').mouseout(function(event) {`( 
http://jsfiddle.net/qgbtd/)
Make sure you are loading jquery in your HTML
Also like the comments say using `mouseleave()` gives it a nicer behavior

Comment: אתה יכול ללחוץ על הוי מתחת לדירוג של השאלה כדי לבחור אותה כתשובה הטובה ביותר

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need jQuery for this. Try to get it working with just CSS first, it's the logical step. If you need animations use CSS3 transitions, and jQuery just as fallback for old browsers if you really need the animations, otherwise just let it be, old browser just won't animate the opacity, no big deal.

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/uqebor/9/edit

```
ul.menu,
ul.menu ul {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
}
ul.menu li {
  margin: 1px 0;
}
ul.menu > li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 .5em;
}
ul.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
}
ul.menu ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
ul.menu li:hover ul {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot
mouseleave approved.

Avi